# How can I connect two portion of my graph? in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Hi all I have a graph which is split in two portion, like I am showing in the photo, I would like to connect the two portion by adding a red edges like I am showing in the photo. Someone know a networkx function to do that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have to calculate anything else (meaning the nodes to be connected are fixed - in the example 4 an 6) a simple

```
G.add_edge(4, 6)
```

will do. ([documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html))